# How do I get an environment parameter in a controller In Symfony 3.4?

Tags: symfony, environment-variables, symfony-3.4

In the `dev` environment of a Symfony 3.4 application, I am trying to store credentials as environment variables. I can’t get it to work, and I can’t figure out what’s missing. This is what I have:

In `app\config\.env` I have an API key defined, like so:

```
GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

In `app\config\services.yml` I have:

```
parameters:
    google.developer.key: "%env(GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY)%"
```

In one of my controllers, I want to pass this parameter to an object like so:

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey($this->getParameter('google.developer.key'));
```

To me, that setup looks fine, but when I try to run it, I get a `EnvNotFoundException` with the following message:

> Environment variable not found: "GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY".

When I put the key in `app\config\services.yml` directly, it works just fine:

```
parameters:
    google.developer.key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

(But that’s not what I want, for a variety of reasons.)

I cleared the `dev` cache, restarted the web server, read the relevant Symfony Documentation (I think), but no luck. I guess I’m missing a step, but I can’t figure out what that would be. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is working for me

Comment: Odd. Thanks, @Smaïne.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symfony 3.4 does not automatically load the `.env` file. You have to modify your `app_dev.php` to load the file:

```
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
...
$dotenv = new Dotenv();
$dotenv->load(__DIR__.'/../app/config/.env');
```

Comment: I guess that makes sense. More importantly: That totally works. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to explictly state the `composer require symfony/dotenv` part.

Comment: Thanks @Francesco Abeni. I did not require this step, though. Isn’t it shipped with Symfony 3.4?

Comment: @ACJ you are correct. That step it not necessary in Symfony 3.4.

Comment: This is actually wrong! Here you are loading certain .env file, but this might NOT be the exact .env file or even the environment variables your Symfony application is using! (think of variables coming from Docker, .env.XXX.local, parameters.yml etc )

Comment: @Sliq your comment is useful, but I don't think my answer is wrong. It answers the original question, which is basically "why my .env file is not loaded?". Of course you can get environment variables from other places, but that's another question IMHO. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The symphony v3.4 [documentation on Environment Variables](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/external_parameters.html) advises using your web server to configure the environment variables.

I couldn't test this as my installation is Symfony v4 and that uses the `/.env` file for configuring environment variables.

Hopefully this helps in some way.

Comment: For production, yes, but for development `.env` file is fine.

Comment: For production that is my plan, but for `dev` this is somewhat impractical for several reasons. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why Initialize the Google_Client in your Controller and not using the service container?

See: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container.html

You can pass that Developer Key in an array with the key developer_key in construct.

Comment: That’s not the issue at hand, but thanks for your suggestion.